# How to set selected value of an array - I have this form many times

Tags: javascript

I have dropdown and it is an array. I'm using JavaScript to clone this dropdown when button "Add" is clicked. So it is appeared many times and it is inserted correct. But when I try to set selected value of this dropdown, when I press submit values of all forms of this dropdown becomes the same. I think this is because I use set_select('labeling[]') as array like this:

```
<option value=''" . set_select('labeling[]', '') . " role='menuitem'> </option>
```

But when I try to use it like that:

```
<option value=''" . set_select('labeling', '') . " role='menuitem'> </option>
```

it doesn't set selected anything. My view is:

```html
 <select name="labeling[]" id="labeling" class="dropdown">
                                    <option value=''" . set_select('labeling[]', '') . " role='menuitem'> </option>
                                        <option value="1" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '1'); ?> role="menuitem">1</option>
                                        <option value="2" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '2'); ?> role="menuitem">2</option>
                                        <option value="3" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '3'); ?> role="menuitem">3</option>
                                        <option value="4" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '4'); ?> role="menuitem">4</option>
                                    </select>
```

How could I do that - to be selected values for each dropdown? :) Thanks!

I edited my question. My whole code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function () {
                var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
                $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function (e) {
                    var $template = $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true);

                   
                    $template.find('input', 'select').val('').focus();
                    $template.appendTo($wrapper);
                });
     });
```

```html
<div class="container multi-field-wrapper">
                <div class="multi-fields">
                    <div class="multi-field">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                   <select name="labeling[]" id="labeling" class="dropdown">
                                    <option value=''" . set_select('labeling[]', '') . " role='menuitem'> </option>
                                        <option value="firm1" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', 'firm1'); ?> role="menuitem">firm1</option>
                                        <option value="firm2" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', 'firm2'); ?> role="menuitem">firm2</option>
                                        <option value="firm3" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', 'firm3'); ?> role="menuitem">firm3</option>
                                        <option value="firm4" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', 'firm4'); ?> role="menuitem">firm4</option>
                                    </select>
                  </div>
                            </div>
</div>
                            </div>
</div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want and element appear selected based on the value coming from database?

Comment: No, I want when user select some of these options and click submit, this option to be still selected. I tried with set_selected('labelling[]') but I'm using Javascript to clone this dropdown and it is overwritten.

Comment: What this function is actually doing? Is returning the already saved value from the database <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '1'); ?> And you want the already saved option selected. Right?

Comment: No, it set selected value of what you have selected. But my problem is that I have this dropdown many times and when user clicks submit, all dropdowns have this selected value.

Comment: I edited my question. I wrote my Javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all lets assume your page name is "A.php". Create a hidden field in this page. ex:

```
<input type="hidden" id="unique_index" value="0" />
<select name="labeling[]">
  <option value="1" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '1', TRUE, 0); ?> role="menuitem">1</option>
  <option value="2" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '2', FALSE, 0); ?> role="menuitem">2</option>
  <option value="3" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '3', FALSE, 0); ?> role="menuitem">3</option>
</select>
```

Now, in javascript (where you were cloning the element earlier that is the function which get invoked on click of button), write a get call like this:

```
var newIndex = $('#unique_index').val();
var cnt = parseInt(newIndex)+1;
$.get( "new_ajax_page_url.php", { counter: cnt} )
  .done(function( data ) {
       data.find('input', 'select').val('').focus();
       data.appendTo($wrapper);
  });
```

Now in the new_ajax_page_url.php, which will only contain:-

```
$newCounter = $_GET['counter'];

$str = <<<EOD
<select name="labeling[]">
  <option value="1" set_select('labeling[]', '1', TRUE, $newCounter) role="menuitem">1</option>
  <option value="2" set_select('labeling[]', '2', FALSE, $newCounter) role="menuitem">2</option>
  <option value="3" set_select('labeling[]', '3', FALSE, $newCounter); role="menuitem">3</option>
</select>
EOD;

echo $str;
```

+++++++

Hope it is helpful :like:

Comment: I'll try it and I'll write. Thanks :)

Comment: I did it! It works, thanks! This is my working code:  var cnt = parseInt(newIndex)+1;
                    $.get( "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/receivedOrders/get_count", { counter: cnt} )
                      .done(function( data ) { var $template = $('.multi_rows:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true);  $template.appendTo($wrapper);
                    });

Answer (score 1):

Try this If I am understanding you problem correctly:

This is a sample case, try to do the way ci does:-

```
$options = array(
                  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
                  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
                );

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');

// Would produce:

<select name="shirts">
<option value="small">Small Shirt</option>
<option value="med">Medium Shirt</option>
<option value="large" selected="selected">Large Shirt</option>
<option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

Do let me know If anything is incorrect anywhere?

Comment: I don't want to be selected definite value. It should be selected dependent of user's choice - what he has been selected - to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the array indices yourself; example:

```
labeling[0]
labeling[1]
labeling[2]
```

Without those indices each option will overwrite the previous one.

Comment: I tried with this, but it's not selected: <select name="labeling[]" id="labeling" class="dropdown">
                                    <option value=''" . set_select('labeling[]', '') . " role='menuitem'> </option>
                                        <option value="firm1" <?php echo set_select('labeling[firm1]', 'firm1'); ?> role="menuitem">firm1</option>
                                        <option value="firm2" <?php echo set_select('labeling[firm2]', 'firm2'); ?> role="menuitem">firm2</option> </select>

Comment: @ci_lover What do you mean by “not selected”? If you want to pre-select an option, you have to state that using [the `selected` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option).

Comment: I want if user selects for example firm1, when form submits, to be selected form1.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not an option is the current selected item is controlled by the `SELECTED` attribute in the option.

```
<select name="labeling[]" id="labeling" class="dropdown">
       <option value="1" role="menuitem">1</option>
       <option value="2" SELECTED role="menuitem">2</option>
       <option value="3" role="menuitem">3</option>
       <option value="4" role="menuitem">4</option>
</select>
```

You haven't shown much of your code so I can only guess based on what you say that when you submit it loses the ability to properly process the PHP function that you are calling.  In this case I would recommend either generating the page with the `SELECTED` option in the appropriate locations or using Javascript to add `SELECTED` to the appropriate options in your lists.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using set_select() on your first select box the integer passes should be 0, on your second select box it should be 1, and so on.... Now the set_select() function does know which key should be used and is able to set the correct value as selected for all your select boxes with an array as field name, YAY!

HTML will look like this:

```
<select name="labeling[]">
  <option value="1" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '1', TRUE, 0); ?> role="menuitem">1</option>
  <option value="2" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '2', FALSE, 0); ?> role="menuitem">2</option>
  <option value="3" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '3', FALSE, 0); ?> role="menuitem">3</option>
</select> 

<select name="labeling[]">
  <option value="1" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '1', TRUE, 1); ?> role="menuitem">1</option>
  <option value="2" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '2', FALSE, 1); ?> role="menuitem">2</option>
  <option value="3" <?php echo set_select('labeling[]', '3', FALSE, 1); ?> role="menuitem">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't show this dropdown many times with for, I show it with Javascript - clone this dropdown. Please see my edited question. I added my javascript code. How to set this key in my case - as I'm using clone with JS? :)

Comment: Cloning will not work in you case. Try ajax for dynamically created the select boxes

Comment: How to use ajax for that? I'm new to javascript.

Comment: Let me post the answer